# Why is 10/3 equal to 3.3333333333333335 instead of ...332 or ..334?

Tags: python

Could someone specifically explain why the last digit is 5 instead of 2 or 4?
Knowing a float must have an inaccuracy in the binary world, I can't get exactly how the result of the case above has been made in detail.

Comment: Read carefully, folks. This isn't the standard "why is this floating point result inaccurate" question. It's more specific: why is the error more than +/-1 in the last digit?

Comment: @JohnKugelman Because binary representation of the number, which seems to be addressed in the other post. Is that not correct?

Comment: @cricket_007: "Because binary", while accurate in a certain sense, is missing too many logical steps for it to qualify as a real explanation. The questioner already knows that floats are binary.

Comment: ObLink: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). And there's lots of good info in the answers to [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 7):

It's because it's the closest a (64bit) `float` can be to the "true value" of `10/3`.

I use cython here (to wrap [`math.h nexttoward`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/nextafter) function) because I don't know any builtin function for this:

```
%load_ext cython

%%cython
cdef extern from "<math.h>" nogil:
    # A function that get's the next representable float for the 
    # first argument in direction to the second argument.
    double nexttoward(double, long double)

def next_float_toward(double i, long double j):
    return nexttoward(i, j)
```

(or as pointed out by @DSM you could also use [`numpy.nextafter`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.coremath.html#c.npy_nextafter))

When I display the values for `10/3` and the previous and next representable float for this value I get:

```
>>> '{:.50}'.format(10/3)
3.3333333333333334813630699500208720564842224121094

>>> '{:.50}'.format(next_float_toward(10/3., 0))
3.3333333333333330372738600999582558870315551757812

>>> '{:.50}'.format(next_float_toward(10/3., 10))
3.3333333333333339254522798000834882259368896484375
```

So each other representable floating point value is "further" away.

Comment: I don't know any built-in function either, but `np.nextafter` is probably simpler.. (although in the answer I was working on I just used `.hex()` and `float.fromhex` to build it manually.)

Answer (score 6):

Because the largest representable value smaller than ...335 is ...330 (specifically, it's smaller by `2**-51`, or one Unit in the Last Place).  ...333 is closer to ...335 than it is to ...330, so this is the best possible rounding.

There are a number of ways to confirm this; MSeifert shows one thing you can do directly with `<math.h>` from C or Cython.  You can also use [this visualization tool](http://bartaz.github.io/ieee754-visualization/) (found by Googling "floating point representation" and picking one of the top results) to play with the binary representation.